# Variation of a Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, bounded-variation

Let $B_t$ be a standard brownian motion. The variation is not bounded on any interval.
What if I can only detect variation of a,ie I only observe the process $[B/a]_t$. Then this is a bounded variation process. Can I explicitly calculate this variation? with the use of local times eventually? then I am thinking this behaves like $1/\sqrt{a}$, by scaling, but I can find any references. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is interesting, but I have a feeling this process is very badly behaved e.g. around $\inf\{t>0:B_t=a\}$ since I think it jumps around infinitely many times in arbitrarily small intervals.

Comment: Actually, another similar way, would be: what is the path length I would calculate if I only had a scale of length $a$.